# How to use title attributes in sidebar widget?

Tags: php, widgets, urls

I have a custom post type "article" & I need to display some custom urls is a widget in the sidebar using `php code widget`.
When I use this code withing the loop it works perfectly:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('/article/full-text/'); ?>
<?php $slug = $post->post_name; echo $slug; ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Full Text</a>
```

but when I put this code in the php code widget it displays only the first part of the url.
To be more clear, when I use this code within the loop the url will be (`www.my-site.com/article/full-text/article-title`). But in the php code widget the url will be (`www.my-site.com/article/full-text/`).
Am I missing something here? Any help please?

Comment: Not really shure what are you trying to do.. why don't u just pass an id of post you want to link to like these: `get_permalink( id );` where id == post/page/cpt id ?

Comment: I need to display custom url so i can use change template feature based on url. thus, i need to split the url & add the custom part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'r missing $post variable ( it is not defined and that for you don't get post_name ).

As a solution you could add `global $post;`

You'r code would be like:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('/article/full-text/'); global $post;
$slug = $post->post_name; echo $slug; ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Full Text</a>
```